# Is there any other use-case of having a decentralised network other than majorly DeFi and GameFi?

Tags: web3js, nft, network, defi, decentralization

I have been familiar with the Web3 ecosystem for almost 2-years now. But I still fail to understand if there is any other real world use-case for a decentralised network other than DeFi, ICOs and NFTs for maybe some games (GameFi) or some raw artwork. Even GameFi isn't fully decentralised. It actually hosts servers on AWS/GCP/Azure and only uses decentralised networks for primarily NFTs. I agree that I am still learning a lot about the space, but I really want to get into some other kinds of projects where web3 could potentially be leveraged.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the case studios of public blockchain real-world use cases at [ValueProp database](https://thevalueprop.io/database).